# Minutes/Actions from Meetings in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, meetings

As an organisation, we use Outlook 2007 to [schedule and arrange meetings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/schedule-a-meeting-HP001230384.aspx).
I want to start getting into the habit of recording minutes/actions from some of these meetings I setup.

I was looking at [Minutes Templates on the MS website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CT010117260.aspx), and these look great, but involve me having to tap in the attendees, meeting location, date, and agenda items.

This got me thinking:
Is there an "Out the Box" way to **have a template pull out the relevant information from the relevant Outlook meeting?**
or perhaps export a Meeting to a Minutes/Actions style template.

- This would be more efficient and then I can just tap in the relevant minutes/action items against the agenda items.

Perhaps it would also allow me to then fwd this minutes/actions to the relevant attendees of that meeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this by just putting the minutes/action items into the body of the meeting AFTER the meeting takes place, then sending an update to all the invitees.  This way everyone gets it and it is directly linked to that meeting in Outlook.